# Process.Start gives wrong IDs on multiple window programs

Tags: c#, windows, ms-office

To be honest, I can't say I actually know where to begin with this question.  So, I'll start from the beginning.

I have C# code that invokes Process.Start based on a OFD box.  Basically allowing the user to open anything from the box, this is absolutely intended.

```
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo starter = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(OFPbasicfile.FileName);
            starter.UseShellExecute = true;


            System.Diagnostics.Process alpha = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            alpha = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(starter);
```

Now, it perfectly executes and opens, but I've noticed something of an odd duck.  If the first file opens say a .docx file I can then read alpha.ID just fine.  However, the next time it opens a .docx file alpha.ID will be assigned a new process ID that corresponds to nothing in the task list.  Worse yet, I get absolutely no useful information from alpha as it now has a handler to a non-existent process.

Near as I can figure this is probably something to do with the fact that the program doesn't realize everything perfectly.  It tries to create a new process and reserves the ID for it, but then the running instance of word, etc. takes ownership of the started file and my program never gets advised of this change.

Ideally I was trying to find a way to track any and every file opened (process ID, window handles, however worked), but now I'd be more than happy if alpha would just recognize that the process is opened by Word (Or Excel, or what have you).

The basic question boils down to this: **When using Process.Start is there any way to ensure it gives the proper process ID (or just the program used to open it) every time?**

Or, alternatively: **Is there any way to set a process variable with a reference to the exact window it opened?**

Comment: Yes, you started a new process. That process then ran some logic and decided to hand information over to an existing process and then exit. The logic, and details of the hand-over are *not* standard. There are plenty of different ways to do this, and different applications will do it differently. You do get the "proper" process ID, it just so happens that that process is about to (or already has) ended itself.

Comment: Okay.  Honestly, I'm kind of glad I got as close as I did to what was actually happening in the code.  I never thought that the process might actually be created before it hands over the information and finally exits.  It makes sense as to why I see so many error values for alpha, so I thank you for that.  The core of the question does kind of remain, is there any way to at least gain reference to the program/process that owns the opened file?  If it's impossible, it's impossible (I'll even accept that as an answer), but I like Process.Start for it's ability to open the default program.